# python group or aggregate multiple columns in a DataFrame based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to rewrite legacy transformation scripts and stuck at an aggregation point in many a scenarios.

For example:
I have a table in SQL Server as below:
userid  dept    groupname       groupid
101     101     All users       1001
202     202     New group       2034
101     103     Admin           1020
101     105     All users       1001

**Below existing code, creates only one document per user and embeds the groups and dept data.**

```
sqlCursor=pypyodbc.connect(sqlConnectionString).cursor()
mongodb=pymongo.MongoClient()
dbo=mongodb.database.collection

userDict=collections.OrderedDict()
sqlCursor.execute(''' select * from table ''')
tuples=sqlCursor.fetchall()
for tup in tuples:
 idi=tup.userid
 groups=userDict.get(idi,collections.OrderedDict()).get('groups', list())
 groups.append({'groupid':tup.groupid,'groupname':tup.groupname})
 dept=userDict.get(idi,collections.OrderedDict()).get('dept', list())
 dept.append(tup.dept)
 doc=collections.OrderedDict()
 doc['userid']=idi
 doc['groups']=groups
 doc['dept']=dept
 userDict['idi']=doc

dbo.insert_many(userDict.values())
```

For the rewriting, we have planned to upgrade the code by using pandas library. I made some progress by populating the data frame as below.

```
df=pandas.read_sql(''' SELECT * FROM TABLE ''',pypyodbc.connect(sqlConnectionString))
```

The below command dumps the entire data frame into mongodb without embedding.

```
dbo.insert_many(df.fillna('NULL_DATA').to_dict('records'))
```

I tried checking few examples of `groupby` in pandas but is not working the way I required.

**How do I group the records using pandas and generate embedded documents in mongodb?**

Please let me know if this could not be achieved using pandas library.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how pymongo needs the data, but I think you need something like this:

```
(
    df.groupby("userid")
    .apply(lambda g: g.to_dict(orient="records").reset_index(name="groups"))
    .to_dict(orient="records")
)
```

I didn't understand how you need to group `depts`, but you can do something similar and then merge it.

Comment: Hi, I did not understand how did you create the column `groups`. In the code columns `groups` is a list of dictionaries created by aggregating the `userid`. How do we do this in pandas?